# How to set Angular Material mat-table cell conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I have the following mat-table and there are Edit and Delete buttons for each record:

```
Name   |   Operation     |
-------|-----------------|
Bob    |   Edit | Delete |
John   |   Edit | Delete |
Willy  |   Edit | Delete |
```

The mat-table structure that I use is as shown below:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="operation">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Operation</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let operation of operations">
        <button [disabled]="row.isActive">
          <mat-icon>{{ operation.icon }}</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </ng-container>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

I want to make enabled/disabled Delete button by sending a parameter ("operation.isDisabled") from parent component and using a column value ("row.isActive") in each row. However, as it is base table, I do not want to use specific values and try to send boty of these 2 conditions in config via "operation" variable like operation.condition = "row.isActive && operation.type === 'delete'". But unfortunately I could not do this via the folowing config (I can pass config, there is no problem. But I need to make it in if condition):

```
this.operation = [
  {
    type: 'delete',
    condition: 'row.isActive && operation.type === "delete"'
  }
];
```

So, is it possible to manipulate a single button usimng these 2 conditions sent from parent component as string, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback to verify it.

Like:
`<button [disabled]="check(operation.type, row.isActive)">`

And whithin check() callback do you perfoms the needed evaluation.

Comment: Thanks amigo, voted up. But I need a generic solution by passing the condition from parent component. Any idea?